# is there an even shorter way to print whichever of two values exists?

Tags: php

I currently am using (essentially) this method to print whichever of two values is non-null, with one having priority over the other:

```
<?php
    $a = "high priority text that may be empty or null";
    $b = "low priority fallback that may also be empty or null";
?>
The value we want to echo is: <?=($a)?$a:$b?>.
```

This can sometimes get long, in code, when it looks more like:

```
The value we want to echo is: <?=($_GET['the_insanely_long_name'])?$_GET['the_insanely_long_name']:$old_val['the_insanely_long_name']?>
```

In some languages, the following type of statement works, but not in PHP:

```
The value we want to echo is: <?=$_GET['the_insanely_long_name']||$old_val['the_insanely_long_name']?>
```

Is there a similar trick in PHP to further shorten or simplify this code?

Comment: i don't think *shorter* at the cost of readability is a good thing

Comment: @Dagon I really see it as quite a bit more readable... print A OR B is pretty obvious and straight-forward, in loose-boolean languages.  print IF A THEN A ELSE B is not anywhere near as human-readable at a glance.

Comment: well that in the eye of the beholder of course, buts it's not clearer to me. A little verbosity is not a bad thing, the puter's are faster enough now with enough memory that we don't use single letter variable names to save space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.3+ you can use the `?:` operator ([manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

```
<?= ($a) ?: $b; ?>
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer.  However, to kill the eventual PHP notice about undefined entries, I had to add the dreaded `@` to the beginning, making the final line of code `<?=@$a?:$b?>`.  It's not perfect, but I'm glad of the reduced code duplication and easier scannability in HTML templates.

Comment: @GregSchoppe congrats, bad practice, poor readability hard to maintain, but hey is *small* ;-)

Comment: @Dagon Consider the scenario of a loooooong HTML form.  The form may a hundred fields in it, and all of them may have submitted values (think server-side validation), existing values (think editing an existing entry), or be blank.  to actually be fully readable for this form, your templates would need to use an if statement with two versions of each input, making your template impossible to read as straight HTML.  Given that most template designers are not PHP savvy, this is bad.  Instead, by using this dirty little snippet, you have a little "magic" php added to basic HTML forms.

Comment: as for "bad practice", the `@` is fine for suppressing errors on straight forward variables, as it is limited in scope, and frankly, there's a reason the "SFTU operator" (`@`) exists.  I have no idea what you mean by "hard to maintain", as the snippet is pretty simple to explain in a style guide.